# Excel VBA - How to format a UserForm TextBox in Time Format

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am making a UserForm in excel that will create an appointment in my Outlook Calendar. Everything is working except the start and end times. Below is my code where DTPicker1 is the Date of the appointment and DTPicker2 and DTPicker3 are the start and end times respectively. They are in dtpTime format. The appointment is created on the right date and subject and everything works correctly except the times. Not sure what I'm supposed to do to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim r As Long

On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If olApp Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Dim mysub, myStart, myEnd
    mysub = TextBox1
    myStart = DTPicker1 & DatePicker2
    myEnd = DTPicker1 & DatePicker3
    Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 'creates a new appointment
    With olAppItem
        'set default appointment values
        .Location = ""
        .Body = ""
        .ReminderSet = True
        .BusyStatus = olFree
        .RequiredAttendees = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        .Start = myStart
        .End = myEnd
        .Subject = TextBox1
        .Attachments.Add ("c:\temp\somefile.msg")
        .Location = ""
        .Body = ""
        .ReminderSet = True
        .BusyStatus = olBusy
        .Categories = "Orange Category" 
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Save 'saves the new appointment to the default folder
    End With
Set olAppItem = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
MsgBox "Done !"
End Sub
```

Comment: The built in text box control does not do it, as you recognized.
What you could possibly to is to respond to textbox changed event
to get the text and format accordingly in code

Comment: I completely forgot that the DatePicker Box in the UserForm can be changed to a time type of format so I was going to use that but now that won't work either. I guess it might be the code I written and not the format. I will edit my question with all my code.

Comment: @gluc7 I don't see where you `Dim myStart As Date` ? It should be `myStart = DTPicker1.value`. What is `myStart = DTPicker1 & DatePicker2` suppose to be ? are you trying to add these dates together ? what exactly ?

Comment: @ShaiRado `Dim myStart As Date` had no effect on it. As for why `myStart` is setup like that, as far as I know that is how you create meeting times in outlook through VBA. There is only one `.Start` line and both the date and time are created there. I could be wrong on this though. I did test doing this based on cells. For example `myStart = DateValue(Cells(r, 3).Value) + Cells(r, 4).Value` where column 3 was the date and column 4 was the start time worked perfectly. Also the meeting is still be created on the correct date, its just the time that won't work which I find odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. I needed to separate out the two variables within myStart and myEnd with a space and connect them with the "&" instead of the "+" as seen in the below code. I also needed to use the TimeValue function on my time DTPicker to properly format it. Thanks for everybody's input!

```
    Dim mysub
    Dim myStart, myEnd As Date
    mysub = TextBox1
    myStart = DTPicker1 & " " & TimeValue(DTPicker2)
    myEnd = DTPicker1 & " " & TimeValue(DTPicker3)
    Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 'creates a new appointment
    With olAppItem
        'set default appointment values
        .Location = ""
        .Body = ""
        .ReminderSet = True
        .BusyStatus = olFree
        .RequiredAttendees = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        .Start = myStart
        .End = myEnd
        .Subject = TextBox1
        .Attachments.Add ("c:\temp\somefile.msg")
        .Location = ""
        .Body = .Subject
        .ReminderSet = True
        .BusyStatus = olBusy
        .Categories = "Orange Category" 'add this to be able to delete the test appointments
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Save 'saves the new appointment to the default folder
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would just make the UI any decent kind of date-time and then format that cell in VBA when submitting to Outlook

```
Dim startDate
Dim endDate
startDate = Format(Range("A1").value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
endDate = Format(Range("A2").value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
' upload to outlook startDate, endDate, appointment details
```

Comment: I won't be pulling the information from cells. Everything sent to Outlook will be directly from the UserForm. I have changed my question a bit as well.